# reverse mysql database results with php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have am grabbing a whole lot of data from a table in a mysql database and displaying it on a page. The code looks like this.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr class="contact-content">
    <td><?php echo $rows['ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['tel_home']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['tel_mobile']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['tel_work']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

It currently displays results like this

**1 | James | example@example.com | 1234567 | 1234567 | 9876**

**2 | Anna | example@example.com | 8768765 | 6543 | 9876**

But I would like to reverse it and display the results something like this ordered by there id

**2 | Anna | example@example.com | 8768765 | 6543 | 9876**

**1 | James | example@example.com | 1234567 | 1234567 | 9876**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Use one of theses queries:

Order by ascending name:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY name ASC";
```

Order by descending ID:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause.

You are looking for a DESCENDING order:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY ID DESC";
```